# Can you use "OK Google" to set a timer with a label by voice?

Tags: clock, voice-command, ok-google

Is it possible to set a timer with a label using "OK Google"?   I'd like to be able to say:

> OK Google: 20 minute timer for laundry

or

> OK Google: laundry timer 20 minutes

but I haven't found a way of phrasing it that actually works.   It just takes me to the Google search results.   I can only say "OK Google: timer 20 minutes."  How do I set the label on a timer using "OK Google"?

Comment: I've never used it but [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice) may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

"Ok google, set alarm label laundry for 20 minutes"

Comment: That works!  But if I replace the word "alarm" by "timer" it does not.  :(

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm a couple years late, but "set timer called 'name' 'duration'" works (most of the time).

Comment: Great answer! You can even be a little more verbose and it'll still work. E.g. "Ok Google", "Set a timer called laundry for 1 hour!".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of this writing it is not possible to set a timer and a label with an OK Google command. OK Google only supports the basic "set timer for x-amount-of-time" and no additional parameters, you could however use the "reminder me to ..." command to have comments/labels as an alternative for short term items or use the "create a calendar event ..." command for items farther in the future as alternatives.

OK Google information [source](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?hl=en)